Left nullspace equals rowspace of nonsingular matrix
I was studying for a Linear Algebra class and I came across the following exercise:
Ex: Let $A^{m\times n}$ be a matrix with $R(A)=p$.
If $P$ is a nonsingular matrix and $U$ is the reduced row echelon form associated with $A$, such that $PA = U$.Show that the last $(m-p)$ rows of $P$ span the left nullspace of $A$.
In other words, if
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{pmatrix}
P_1\\
P_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with $P_2^{(m-p)\times m}$ matrix, then $N(A^T) = C(P_2^T)$, where $N(A^T)$ is the left nullspace of $A$ and $C(P_2^T)$ is the rowspace of $P_2$.
My attempt is given below,kindly check and help me proceed
Thanks!
My Attempt: I was able to make a little bit of progress, showing $C(P_2^T)\subseteq N(A^T)$ in the following way:
Since $PA = U$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
P_1\\
P_2
\end{pmatrix} A = U = \begin{pmatrix}
U_1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $0$ is a $(m-p)\times n$ matrix with null entries. This implies that $P_2A = 0$ and therefore $A^TP_2^T = 0$. Then, $\forall x\in C(P_2^T)$, we have:
\begin{equation}
x = P_2^Ty \implies A^T x=A^T P_2^T y = 0 y = 0
\end{equation}
Therefore, $C(P_2^T)\subseteq N(A^T)$. How could I show $N(A^T)\subseteq C(P_2^T)$?

What are the last $m-p$ rows of $U$?

What can you say about the dimensions of the spaces?

More directly (without going to the transposé matrices):
$$P_2A=0$$
means precisely that the rows of $P_2$ (i.e. the last $m-p$ rows of $P$) belong to the left nullspace of $A$.
Now, since $P$ is invertible, these rows  are linearly independent, hence they span a space of dimension $m-p$. And by the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the left nullspace of $A$ is also $m-p$, so you are done.
